# NaN In quadratic equation program

Tags: java, eclipse

Anyways I can make this more efficient and also I keep getting NaN for an answer i need help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RLAQuadraticEquation {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int FOUR = 4;
    double a, b, c, discriminant, posQuadEquation, negQuadEquation, disc;

    System.out.print("Enter a value for a");
    a = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter a value for b");
    b = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter a value for c");
    c = in.nextDouble();
    in.close();

    disc = Math.sqrt((b*b) - (FOUR*a*c));
    discriminant = (b*b) - (FOUR*a*c);

    if(Math.abs(discriminant) > 0.00000001){
        posQuadEquation = Math.round(- b + Math.sqrt(disc))/(2*a);
        negQuadEquation = Math.round(-b - Math.sqrt(disc))/(2*a);
        System.out.println("The roots are" + posQuadEquation + "and" + negQuadEquation);
    }
    else if ((discriminant) <= (0.00000001)){
        posQuadEquation = (-b+ Math.sqrt(disc))/(2*a);
        System.out.println("The root is: " + posQuadEquation);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No roots");
    }   
}
```

Im having a lot of trouble any feedback or advice would help!
Thank you!!

Comment: You're pretty unlikely to get homework help here, especially with a question like this. Take a look at how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know they tell you to use constants, and that's often good practice... but `final int FOUR = 4;` doesn't have much of a purpose.  Just use 4.

Comment: if (discriminant) <= (0.00000001) is true, you shouldn't be doing any math.  Just print "no roots".  Also,  I would change it to (if discriminant< 0)

Comment: @NickZiebert But if the discriminant is 0, there can be a root.

Comment: Yeah, your first if statement should be if(Math.abs(discriminant) >= 0)  and second should be if(Math.abs(discriminant) < 0)

Comment: For what input are you getting NaN?

Comment: `Math.sqrt(disc)` is the square root of a square root.  Is that what you intended?  And why are you using `Math.round`?

Comment: Im inputting a .9 b .6 c.1 and im using math.round because i was told to round

Answer (score 1):

When you use .9 .6 and .1 as the inputs, the discriminant is calculated as -5.551115123125783E-17 instead of zero.  This is because of how floating point number are handled (they aren't always exact), and it's likely why they told you to round.  But, because the discriminant is calculated as very slightly below zero, taking the square root gives NaN (because the square root of a negative number is imaginary.)

You have this check:

```
if(Math.abs(discriminant) > 0.00000001){
```

to see if the discriminant is near zero.  But if it is near zero, you do:

```
posQuadEquation = (-b+ Math.sqrt(disc))/(2*a);
```

But you *know* the discriminant is zero at this point.  So you can skip taking the square root, and you can even skip adding or subtracting it.  You could just do this:

```
posQuadEquation = (-b)/(2*a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've handled the complex portion of the roots at all if the discriminant is < 0.

You'll want to check for whether the discriminant is positive (real roots) or negative (complex roots) and then proceed accordingly.  Also it's probably a good idea to have a check for if a == 0 to ensure you have a real quadratic equation and protect against dividing by 0.  You may also want to do some additional protection against non-double inputs from the user, but I haven't included any of that.

Here's some modifications to your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int FOUR = 4;
    double a, b, c, discriminant, realPart, imPart, posQuadEquation, disc;

    System.out.println("Enter a value for a");
    a = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter a value for b");
    b = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter a value for c");
    c = in.nextDouble();
    in.close();

    // if a == 0 it's not a true quadratic, and you would be dividing by 0.
    if (a == 0) {
        System.out.println("Non-Quadratic Equation, \"a\" should not equal 0");
    } else {
        discriminant = (b*b) - (FOUR*a*c);
        boolean isImaginary = false;
        // we've got real roots
        if (discriminant >= 0) {
            disc = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
        // there's a complex part to the roots
        } else {
            isImaginary = true;
            disc = Math.sqrt(-discriminant);
        }

        if(disc > 0.00000001){
            realPart = - b/(2*a);
            imPart = disc/(2*a); 
            String posEq = (realPart + imPart) + "";
            String negEq = (realPart - imPart) + "";
            if (isImaginary) {
                posEq = realPart + " + " + imPart + "i";
                negEq = realPart + " - " + imPart + "i";
            }
            System.out.println("The roots are: " + posEq + " and " + negEq);
        }
        else if (disc <= (0.00000001)){
            posQuadEquation = (-b + disc)/(2*a);
            System.out.println("The root is: " + posQuadEquation);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("No roots");
    }
}
```